# Python (mod-wsgi) hangs when importing from SymPy

Tags: python, module, import, timeout, scipy

I can `import sympy` without a problem, but when I `from sympy import linalg` or `import scipy.linalg`, the request hangs out. I can't seem to find anything in the server logs about it either, and `curl` times out.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong will be greatly appreciated. If I comment out that single line, my program goes right ahead until it needs the module. Also, if I have an empty file with just that line, the request will hang (whereas `import scipy` immediately returns an error message that it is missing the wsgi application function).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the module isn't installed in the `PYTHONPATH` and/or mod_wsgi is compiled against a different Python interpreter than the one you're using from the command-line.  Double check!